# Reloading a PyQt5 App without Restarting it first

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pyqt5

I have created an app and on one of the Windows (`CreateProjectWindow(QDialog)`) I complete a form which I then submit using `self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.getInfo)`.

On submission, I want the `self.tableComboBox` in `UpdateProjecWindow(QDialog)` automatically and immediately updated without me having to first restart the application. The last four lines of code in `CreateProjectWindow(QDialog)` is all I have tried but none of them works. Below is snippet of the code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from datetime import date
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import * 
import sys 
import os
import subprocess
import pandas as pd
import time


Class CreateProjectWindow(QDialog):

     def __init__(self):
          super(CreateProjectWindow, self).__init__()

          self.setWindowTitle("Create a new project") 
          self.setGeometry(100, 100, 300, 400) 
          self.timeStampLineEdit = QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString('MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss')
          self.surnameLineEdit = QLineEdit()
          self.firstnameLineEdit = QLineEdit()
          self.dateOfBirthLineEdit = QDateEdit(calendarPopup=True, displayFormat='MM-dd-yyyy') 
          self.createForm()
          self.buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
          self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.getInfo) 
          self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject) 

     def getInfo():
         output = {'timestamp': self.timeStampLineEdit,\ 
                   'surname' : self.surnameLineEdit,\
                   'firstname' : self.firstnameLineEdit,\
                   'dob' : self.dateOfBirthLineEdit}
         df = pd.DataFrame(output, index=[0])
         df.to_excel('to/some/local/path/profiles_data.xlsx')

         return None

         QApplication.processEvents() # attempt 1 but doesn't work
         QApplication(sys.argv).reload() # attempt 2 but doesn't work
         subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, FILEPATH]) # attempt 3 restarts the app which I don't want
         os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, * sys.argv) # attempt 4 restarts the app which I don't want.

     def creatForm(self):
        layout = QFormLayout() 
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Surname"), self.surnameLineEdit) 
        layout.addRow(QLabel("First Name"), self.firstnameLineEdit)
        layout.addRow(QLabel("D.O.B"), self.dateOfBirthLineEdit)
        self.formGroupBox.setLayout(layout) 
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout() 
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.formGroupBox) 
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.buttonBox) 
        self.setLayout(mainLayout) 

class UpdateProjectWindow(QDialog): 
  
    def __init__(self): 
        super(UpdateProjectWindow, self).__init__() 
        self.setWindowTitle("Parameter Inputs") 
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 300, 400) 
        self.formGroupBox = QGroupBox("Some Window") 
        
        self.tableComboBox = QComboBox()
        
        df = pd.read_excel('to/some/local/path/profiles_data.xlsx')

        names = df['surname']

        self.tableComboBox.addItems(names)

        createForm()

        self.buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel) 
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.processInfo) 
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject) 
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout() 
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.formGroupBox) 
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.buttonBox) 
        self.setLayout(mainLayout) 

    def processInfo(self):
        get_name = self.tableComboBox.currentText()
        print(get_name)

    def createForm(self):
        layout = QFormLayout() 
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Select Surname"), self.tableComboBox)
        self.formGroupBox.setLayout(layout) 

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # setting window title 
        self.setWindowTitle("MyApp") 
  
        # setting geometry to the window 
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 400, 10) 

        self.window1 = CreateProjectWindow()
        self.window2 = UpdateProjectWindow()

        l = QVBoxLayout()
        button1 = QPushButton("Create a Project") 
        button1.clicked.connect(
            lambda checked: self.toggle_window(self.window1)
        )
        l.addWidget(button1)

        button2 = QPushButton("Update a Project")
        button2.clicked.connect(
            lambda checked: self.toggle_window(self.window2)
        )
        l.addWidget(button2)
        
        w = QWidget()
        w.setLayout(l)
        self.setCentralWidget(w)

    def toggle_window(self, window):
        if window.isVisible():
            window.hide()
        else:
            window.show()

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Please be more careful when attaching code: your example contains multiple problems ("Class" should be lowercase, there are lots of indentation problems, function calls to both `createForm` are wrong, and there are attributes that are used before being declared). Always try your code before pasting it, we should concentrate on what your code does, not on correcting your syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is normally no need to restart a Qt application, and certainly this is not required for your case: restarting the QApplication is almost like closing the program and opening it again, doing that just to update some data doesn't make any sense at all.

A possible solution is to create a custom signal for the first window class, which will be emitted when the database is updated, then connect that signal to a function in the other window that loads the data (which means that that function will also be called at the beginning).

```
class CreateProjectWindow(QDialog):
    dataChanged = pyqtSignal()

    # ...

    def getInfo(self):
        # note that your original data was completely wrong, as you tried to add
        # the *widgets* to the frame, while you need to add their *values*
        output = {'timestamp': self.timeStampLineEdit,
               'surname' : self.surnameLineEdit.text(),
               'firstname' : self.firstnameLineEdit.text(),
               'dob' : self.dateOfBirthLineEdit.date().toString()}
        df = pd.DataFrame(output, index=[0])
        df.to_excel('to/some/local/path/profiles_data.xlsx')
        self.dataChanged.emit()
        self.accept()


class UpdateProjectWindow(QDialog): 
    def __init__(self): 
        # ...
        self.tableComboBox = QComboBox()
        self.updateData()

        self.createForm()
        # ...

    def updateData(self):
        self.tableComboBox.clear()
        df = pd.read_excel('to/some/local/path/profiles_data.xlsx')
        names = df['surname']
        self.tableComboBox.addItems(names)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.window1.dataChanged.connect(self.window2.updateData)
```

<sup>Besides that, you must be much more careful with your code: I spent more time to correct your syntax and bugs than to actually give you this answer. Note that there are various other problems with your example, but I will not address them here as it's off topic. In essence, you must put more attention when writing programs.</sup>

Comment: Thanks @musicamante. I have tried implementing your solution but I think the output in getInfo() has blank fields at the time of connecting because I get the following error:

`ValueError: No engine for filetype: ''`

Comment: Thanks once again @musicamante, the issue is resolved. I changed the following for it to work:

From:
`self.window1.dataChanged.connect(self.window2.updateData)`

To:
`self.window1.dataChanged.connect(self.window2.__init__)`

Comment: @MichaelKateregga No, NO! That's really a **bad**, **terrible** idea! If you have that error then you probably did something wrong, from that error it's probably the path (as said, you should be more careful with your syntax). Calling the `__init__` because of an error like that is completely and absolutely wrong (actually, it is wrong in any case, unless you really, *really* know what you're doing). Errors should be solved based on their messages, not trying to do random things. If you see the fuel light switching on while you're driving, you don't jump off the window to go and buy a new car.

Comment: Hi @musicamante, the error was due to calling updateData when it was not yet populated with data, i.e. surname, firstname fields etc. were empty strings ' ' so the rest of my code would not work. Calling __init__ somehow populates all the fields and updates the second Window. I didn't give you the full code but that updateData function has a couple of comboBox that get updated on currentTextChanged in other comboBox. You can send me an email at michaelk@aims.ac.za for further discussion on this please.

Comment: I don't see what there should be to discuss. If the data is empty during the `__init__`, add checks that correctly avoid the problem, or you correctly implement the updateData function. Calling *again* the init as a work around is just laziness, it is **not** a solution, and will certainly create *big* problems sooner or later.